# Difficulty implementing the anchor prop on a custom Icon in React Native Maps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I am trying to display a custom png icon anchored at the bottom middle of the image (the point) on my mapview. I create the icon in another file called CustomIcon.js as seen below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
Image,
View,
} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

export default class CustomIcon extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const driver = this.props.driver ?
        this.props.driver :
        { uid: "noDriversPassed", 
            location: { latitude: 0, longitude: 0 }
        }


    const  coordinate = new MapView.AnimatedRegion({
        latitude: driver.location.latitude,
        longitude: driver.location.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0,
        longitudeDelta: 0,
    })
    this.state = {
        driver: driver,
        coordinate: coordinate,
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <MapView.Marker.Animated
            coordinate={this.state.coordinate}
            anchor={{x: 1, y: .5}}
            ref={marker => { this.marker = marker }}
            style={{width: 50, height: 50}} >
            <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/PictureIcon.png')}
                style={{
                    width: 70,
                    height: 74.2,
                }} />

        </MapView.Marker.Animated>
    )
}
}
```

The actual Mapview screen for my app is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import CustomIcon from '../components/CustomIcon'
import { CurrentLocationButton } from '../components/CurrentLocationButton'

const RootStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(); // Nesting the page within a stack navigator fixes 
the double header issue

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {  
  region: null,    
}
this._getLocationAsync();
}

 _getLocationAsync = async () => {
   let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
     if(status !== 'granted')
       console.log('Permission Denied');
   let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({enableHighAccuracy: true})
   let region = {
     latitude: location.coords.latitude,
     longitude: location.coords.longitude,
     latitudeDelta: 0.045,
     longitudeDelta: 0.045,
   }

   this.setState({region: region})
   }

 centerMap() {
   const { latitude, 
     longitude, 
     latitudeDelta, 
     longitudeDelta } = this.state.region;

this.map.animateToRegion({
  latitude,
  longitude,
  latitudeDelta,
  longitudeDelta,
})
}

render() {  
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <CurrentLocationButton cb={() => {this.centerMap() }}/>
    <MapView
      initialRegion={this.state.region}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      showsCompass={true}
      rotateEnabled= {false}
      ref={(map) => {this.map = map}}
      style={{flex: 1, zIndex: 0}}>
      <CustomIcon driver={{uid: 'null', location: {
        latitude: 42.187527,
        longitude: -121.709072,
      }}} />
    </MapView>
  </View>
);
}
}

 export default class MapNavigator extends React.Component {
 state = {}

 render() {
     return(
     <RootStackNavigator.Navigator>
         <RootStackNavigator.Screen 
             name="Jobs Near Me"
             component={App}
         />
     </RootStackNavigator.Navigator>)
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: '#fff',
 },
});
```

Finally, the image I am using is this:
[image]

I want the image to render on the mapview and be anchored on the bottom point of the image and stay there as the map is zoomed in and out. Instead, the image is anchored in the top left corner, so the point will start in Utah and end in Mexico as the screen is zoomed out. I have tried changing the x and y arguments for the anchor prop and using the actual image size as arguments (rather than anchor={{x: 1, y: .5}}, anchor={{x: 70, y: 37}} and I have tried adjusting the x and y anchor values in many other ways but cannot get the anchor point to change. There are no error messages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this issue. I was using  MapKit on IOS, therefore the prop was centerOffset rather than anchor. When I made the change it anchored the image in the bottom middle of the image as intended.